# How Do I, in Gnuplot, Make a 3d Chart Where the filename is ztics

Tags: csv, gnuplot, filenames, z-axis

Just like the title sounds...

I have some number of files where the filename are the year of the data set represented.

I would also like to use the first column as text for the x axis, second column as the y. The first row as label information...

```
set datafile separator ","
filelist=system("ls")
ztics=list
splot for [i=1:words(list)] word(list,i) using 0:1:list with lines
```

I tried the previous code with no luck and I'm not exactly sure I understand the syntax of Gnuplot

A bit of the file format I'm using:

```
Source,Count
Foo,8452
Bar,8304
```

I want to use the filename to track changes over some dates.

Comment: Please show a the first few lines of data from one of your files.  It is unclear from your question which columns hold text and which hold numerical values.  You ask about using the filename as "ztics", but it is unclear how a file name should be mapped to a z coordinate.  Do you mean that each file contains only x/y data to be drawn in a single plane at some fixed z value?   I.e. All data in  file 3 lies in the plane z=3 or something like that?

Comment: I would like to use the filename as a date stamp on a axis. The first column I would like to treat as text and the second column as value of the text.

Comment: @jumbothecomedian it's not clear to me how the graph should look like. If you really need to do a "3D"-plot typically, the values would be on the z-axis and some labels and/or numbers (e.g. years) on the x- and y-axis. Could you maybe provide a freehand sketch how it should look like? Furthermore, do all your datafiles have all the same texts "Foo","Bar", ... in the same sequence?

Answer (score 0):

"*I would like to use the filename as a date stamp on a axis. The first column I would like to treat as text and the second column as value of the text.*"

OK. We use the filename as a title and `title at beginning` places it on the y axis at the start of that plot.  I added a bunch of spaces at the end of the filename to shift it left so that it would not sit on top of the first label.

`using 0:2:1 with labels` uses the line number in the file as the x coordinate, uses the 2nd column as the value, and the 1st column as a text label.

I plot the data as lines also, so you can see which line the label belongs to.

```
file1.dat
  A  2
  B  1
  C  3
file2.dat
  E  4
  F  2
  G  3
```

gnuplot script

```
set border 3
set tics scale 0
set style textbox opaque
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
set ytics (0, 2.5, 5)
filelist = system("ls -1")
plot for [FILE in filelist] FILE using 0:2 with lines title FILE."      " at beginning, \
     for [FILE in filelist] FILE using 0:2:1 with labels boxed notitle
```

[image]

But this may not be what you really want, because you referred to a 3D plot and a z axis.  Also if two labels end up at the same [x,y] you only see one of them; perhaps that isn't a problem for your actual data.  If it's too far from what you really want to help, perhaps you can give a link to a plot (could be from anywhere) that more or less looks like what you have in mind.